# Asp.Net Mvc Layout and Partial- view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, asp.net-mvc-partialview

there.. I'am really confused about Layout and PartialLayout.
I don't know what wrong I'am doing.
When I login as Admin I can se all links even this Admin links ("Register", "Role", "Department" and "Manage") plus Logout link. So far so good.
But when I click any link of Admin links then my Layout changes as I'am not Admin I mean I see only "Home" , "About" "kontakt" ANd very confusing my logout link changes to Login after all I'am logged. So I'am logged but shows me Login instead.
Then if I click "Home"..or About.. then I see all links again and Logout link.
Please I'am new to this staffs and show me by coding if it's Ok, becouse I couldn't fix this problem in many hours ...

Here is my one of the admin html "Role"

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApiDemo.Models.RoleViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

In my Index.cshtml , _Layout is included.
Here is my _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")



</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application namn", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>



                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </ul>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my _LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && ViewData.ContainsKey("FullName"))
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Role", "Index", "Role")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Department", "Index", "Department")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage", "Pass", "Account")</li>
            }

            <li>

                @Html.ActionLink("Welcome back " + (ViewData["FullName"]) + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })

            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Does `ViewData` contain a value for `FullName`? (and why are you using that condition anyway?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for your response. Yes ViewData contain value and I can see my Full name. I use condition becouse I have to kind of users. I don't want to show Role, Register..to all, only to Admins. I have tried to create two kind of Layout Views but when it comes to _LoginPartial.. then it goes wrong. Now I have added my Role.html file too  to my code.

Comment: But you claiming you cant see it because the code in the `else` block is generated - i.e. your `Login` link, not the `LogOff`. And what do you mean you have created _two kind of Layout Views_ - you have not (your `_LoginPartial` is a partial view, not a layout)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean I tried with two different Layout Views.